# Google Adwords UI causing monitor to stop working

Tags: google-chrome, display, multiple-monitors

This morning the display on one of my two Dell P2312H monitors went off and a message came up telling me: "Current input timing is not supported by the monitor display".  I tried unplugging it and plugging it back in - it came back on and then did the same after a few seconds.

I tried switching the ports the monitors are plugged into and the DVI leads themselves, but the same monitor kept failing and the other one worked fine.  If I changed the resolution to a smaller one it worked again, but looked crap.  I was about ready to push the button on buying a new monitor when I switched my Google Chrome window over onto the other monitor, and then than went off!

So I bookmarked all the tabs I had open, closed Chrome and then systematically opened the bookmarks until I discovered the culprit: my Google AdWords dashboard.  I then tried it in Edge and the same thing happened.

I can open the dashboard on my laptop display and everything is fine, then as I bounce the browser window to the monitor to its left, it goes off, then bounce it again to the monitor on *its* left, that goes off.

Any idea where I can start to figure out a solution to this?

Comment: Can you see what happens if you disable hardware acceleration in Chrome? https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=chrome+disable+hardware+acceleration

Comment: No, that doesn't make a difference.